# Rails is angry that I am instantiating a child from a parent class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I have an object Animal, and when I pass in a type I choose one of the subclasses and instantiate it there.  So something like:

```
class Museum::Animal

    def initialize type

        case type
        when "cat"
           CatAnimal.new
        when "dog"
           DogAnimal.new
        end
    end
end
```

But Rails is giving me the error: Expected ..file path ../animal.rb to define Animal

The file in question is in lib/museum/animal.rb

Comment: What file is that class in and where is it located?

Comment: it's in lib/name_space/animal.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module Barn
  # parent class
  class Animal
     def say
       'default'
     end
  end

  # inheritance for cat
  class Cat < Animal
    def say
      "meow"
    end
  end

  #inheritance for dog
  class Dog < Animal
  end

  # Factory to get by "type"
  def self.get type
    case type
    when :dog
      Dog.new
    when :cat
      Cat.new
    end 
  end 
end
```

and store this as lib/barn.rb.  Then you can do:

```
require 'barn'

c = Barn.get :cat
 => #<Barn::Cat:0x0000010719ffe8> 
c.say
 => "meow" 

d = Barn.get :dog
 => #<Barn::Dog:0x00000107190408> 
d.say
 => "default"
```

Comment: There are inherited methods that cat needs from animal, so they both have to be classes don't they?

Comment: @jeremy Updated to reflect inheritance

Comment: @jeremy Updated to include the factory to get the animal by type

Comment: Thanks for the help Wes.  One more question, is there a way to add a class as part of the module and still have the text exist in another file?  In the problem I'm working on, there are going to eventually be 20 or more of these subclasses.  That is why I went with the separate file structure that I have now.

Comment: @Jeremy Indeed there is but that is a whole nother answer for me to post